# Error al conectar con localhost

Tags: android

Could you help me with my problem?

I am trying to access localhost to obtain the data from a table but I get an error **HttpHostConnectException** when i run it

COMPLETE ERROR: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost refused

Code used:

```
public class MysqlConnectActivity extends Activity {
private TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
}

private class DownloadPoints extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/leerDatosUsuarios.php");
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httppost);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String s = "";
            while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error en la conexion HTTP: "+e.toString());
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        tv.append("\nREAD FROM MYSQL:\n" + result);
    }
}

public void readWebpage(View view) {
    DownloadPoints task = new DownloadPoints();
    task.execute( "http://localhost/leerDatosUsuarios.php");

}
```

Thank you for your attention
Alvaro

Comment: is there an English version of your post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localhost is your actual android device.

If you are trying to access your development machine, you need to access 10.0.2.2 from the emulator.

Comment: I don't use emulator, i run in my android phone. I've tried with 192.168.1.4 and same error than 10.0.2.2 :(

Comment: I use mi ip adress (in ipconfig view in MS2) and i read "You don't have permission to access /leerDatosUsuarios.php on this server"

Comment: probably an issue with your firewall, then